# SSRS: Can you force textboxes on same row to have different height?

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, ssrs-tablix

**DISCLAIMER**: All of this information is completely fake on the report for testing purposes.

I have a report which contains a text box that is getting back a lot of data from a query. The issue is that it is pushing down another text box in a different row, and I am trying to fix that. Here is what the end result is, and the red box indicates the space I am trying to eliminate:

[image]

It should look like this:
[image]

The designer looks as such:
[image]

As you can, **the text box on the left side with the expression under "Dose/Frequency/Route" is expanding down**, and forcing the third text box (which will say ICD-9-CM(DATE) on the report) on the right side to push down, when it *needs* to be right under the text box above it.

I've spent awhile on this, and don't have much experience with SSRS so some guidance would be awesome. I tried putting an extra text box next to the one causing issues and changed its colspan from 10 to 9 but that didn't change anything. Here is an example (colors are just there to help me see where text box is going):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might try wrapping the two textboxes in a rectangle: [Rectangles and Lines (Report Builder and SSRS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239352.aspx)

This will allow you to have a bit more control over the layout. This is similar to doing tables based web page design, yhere are usualy better ways but sometimes this is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

This is called **Merged Rows** (which I have no doubt has been mentioned in previous post) as opposed to Merged Columns (cells). There is no quick fix like a menu option that merges rows so what you have to is conceptually place a tablix inside a tablix. So in your scenario you start with parent tablix that is say 1 detail row and 2 columns (maybe 3 if you need to include a dummy column in the middle), then in each cell replace the textbox with a rectangle (by simply right click the textbox and inserting a rectangle). In the 2 rectangles you insert a tablix in each but first keep only one column and remove the detail row and then position it in the top left corner and then configure each child tablix individually as per what you already have by adding as many rows as necessary and finally make the rectangle same size as the tablix. So as per your screen shot the child tablix in column 1 will have 2 rows, and column 2's tablix will have 4 rows. In that way your parent columns or rather child tablix's can grow independent of each other.